# Dropdown keyboard trap only working on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

Trying to build out a keyboard trap to make navigation dropdown elements keyboard accessible. The intended functionality is suppose to work where once a user tabs to a dropdown element they can press the down arrow to open the dropdown and trigger the focus trap on the child elements and while inside the submenu when they press up the focus trap is remove and returns back to the trigger. Everything works the only issue is this code is only working on the first element.

````
export default function() {

    
    const trigger = $('#active-focus-trigger');
    const container = $('.navPage-subMenu')

    const focusTrap = focusTrapPackage.createFocusTrap('.navPage-subMenu', {
        allowOutsideClick: true,
        
    });

    trigger.on("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.key === "ArrowDown") {
            console.log(e);
            e.preventDefault();
            $(e.currentTarget).parent().addClass('active-focus');
            focusTrap.activate();
        }
    });

    container.on('keydown', function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();  
        if(trigger.parent().hasClass('active-focus') && e.key === "ArrowUp") {
            trigger.parent().removeClass('active-focus');
            focusTrap.deactivate();
        }
    })
        
}```
````